# Rails: Bootstrap and dropdown not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my application.html.erb, I have the following:

```
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/", "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js", "application" %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
```

In my gemfile, I have the following:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

In my views\layouts_header.html.erb, I have:

```
  <li class="dropdown" id="admin_menu">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#admin_menu">
      <%= ADMIN_TITLE %>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <% Admin_menu.each do |menu_text, menu_action| %>
          <li><a href="<%= menu_action %>"><%= menu_text %></a></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Admin_menu is defined elsewhere as:
    Admin_menu = Hash.new
    Admin_menu["Papers"] = "/papers"
    Admin_menu["Tracks"] = "/tracks"
    Admin_menu["Attendance"] = "/attendance"

When I click on the caret, nothing happens. I checked the HTML code, and the dropdown menu selections are there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors coming up when you click on the dropdown menu (or prior to that, such as when the page loads)?

Also, is there a reason you're including your `application.js` three times? You've got it referenced in all of your `javascript_include_tag` calls - you only need it once.  I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be causing this problem though, but it wouldn't hurt to fix.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I cleaned out the application.js includes. I do not see any javascript errors. The caret changes from grey to black when I hover over it, but nothing happens. When I hover over the admin menu, the selector does not change to a hand either.

Comment: Try adding `href="#"` to the dropdown link itself (the one with class `dropdown-toggle`).

Comment: changing data-target="#admin_menu" to href="#admin_menu" did produce a change. When the cursor hovers over the caret or Admin, it changes to a hand, but still no dropdown

Comment: I have the same problem, and if I remove Stripe's `<script>` element, the dropdown starts working.

Comment: @myself: The problem wasn't Stripe per se, but the fact that I was inadvertently re-loading `application.js` at the same time. See my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change these lines:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/", "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js", "application" %>
```

to this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Your current code includes application.js many times, which is a problem for Bootstrap's dropdown code. I'll bet if you look in your application.js file, you'll see this near the top:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

That would mean you're loading bootstrap once every time you include application.js, then again from github.

If you read Bootstrap's Dropdown JS code, you'll see it adds a click listener to *toggle* the dropdown menu. If you run this code twice, you're adding two click listeners. So on every click, those two listeners open the menu and suddenly close it again.

I had a problem similar to yours, where I didn't notice that my `javascript_include_tag` for Stripe was also re-including `application`. I guess we probably copy/pasted from the same place!

Comment: It was including the javascript twice for me as well. After much head scratching I found a javascript_include_tag at the bottom of the application layout as well.

Comment: Any chance you included turbolinks in your app? I removed this from application.js and it solved the issue for me.

Comment: I had a bootstrap.js.coffee file that was conflicting with require bootstrap in application.js. Good catch.

Comment: I had required both bootstrap and bootstrap-sprockets. Worked for me after I removed one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug or chrome extension to check html in the browser. If it is not correct try using the helper to avoid messing with strings:

`<li><%= link_to menu_text, menu_action %></li>`

Comment: In my question, I mentioned that the HTML is fine and the dropdown menu selections are there.